# Calculating operator norm of operator $(Ax)(k) = \int_{0}^{1} x(t)\operatorname{arcctg}\left((-1)^kt\right) \,\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I have no idea how to solve this:

$$A: CL_1[0,1] \rightarrow \ell_\infty$$

$$(Ax)(k) = \int_{0}^{1} x(t)\operatorname{arcctg}\left((-1)^kt\right) \,\mathrm{d}t,\quad\forall x \in CL_1[0,1],\quad\forall k \in \mathbb{N}.$$

I need to calculate the norm of A

UPD:
By $CL_1$ i mean the space of continuous functions on the [a,b] with the norm
$||f|| = \max_{x \in [a, b]} |f(x)|$

As I understood,

$$\forall x \in \ell_\infty\quad\lVert x\rVert_\infty = \sup_n\lvert x_n\rvert$$

$$\forall x \in CL_1[0,1] \rightarrow \lVert x\rVert_c = \max_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)| < + \infty$$

$$\implies  \lvert(Ax)(k)\rvert \leq 1 \cdot \|x\|_c,\quad\forall k \in \mathbb{N}.$$

But I don't know what to do globally.

Comment: What do you mean by $CL_1$? And what do you need to do? Compute the operator norm, I guess from the title. Can you recall the definition?

Comment: Sorry, i mean the space of continuous functions on the segment [a,b] with the norm
$||f|| = max_{x \in [a, b]} |f(x)|$
Yes, i need to calculate the norm of A

Comment: Start by exploring case $k =0$.

Comment: How did you arrive at your last inequality?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\dt}{\mathrm dt}$

I'll use a different notation:
$$A:(C([0,1]), \| f\|_{\infty})\to (\ell^{\infty}, \| (x_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}\|_{\infty}) $$
where $((Af)_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ is defined as $(Af)_k=\int_0^1f(t)\operatorname{arccot}((-1)^kt)\dt$.

Note that:
$$\begin{split}
\|((Af)_k)_{k\in \Bbb N} \| _{\infty}&=\sup_{k\in \Bbb N} \left|\int_0^1f(t)\operatorname{arccot}((-1)^kt)\dt\right|\\ &\le \sup_{k\in \Bbb N} \int_0^1|f(t)||\operatorname{arccot}((-1)^kt)|\dt \\ &\le\|f\|_{\infty}\sup_{k\in \Bbb N} \int_0^1|\operatorname{arccot}((-1)^kt)|\dt \end{split}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I would love to, but I don't really understand how such tasks are solved, so if you can help me complete the solution, it would be great. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @worstfunctionalanalytic can you compute the integral when $k$ is odd and even?